# Simpler Object To Object mapping in Typescript type guarding

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I want to map an object to object for type guard.

As the limitation of object key restricted to string, we only can do string to object mapping.

Here is my workaround solution to do object to object mapping by mapping object to string, and then get the object from map by that string.

```
type Model = Article | User
type ModelName<M> = M extends Article ? 'Article' : M extends User ? 'User' : never

interface ModelOptionMap {
  Article: Prisma.ArticleSelect
  User: Prisma.UserSelect
}
type Options<M> = ModelName<M> extends keyof ModelOptionMap ? ModelOptionMap[ModelName<M>] : never
const options: Options<User> = {}
```

Any better way to achieve this? Or is any advance solution to convert type to name of that type for mapping without using long extends pattern? Or is it Possible to do something like `StringOf<T>` to get the name of T as string literal type?

Comment: you can't convert a type/interface name to a string literal type. So unless there is any other similarities between a `Model` member and a `ModelOptionMap` which can be used for discrimination, there is no better way (other than modifying the existing types to include more information for referencing). But showing us these types would be helpful.

Comment: @TobiasS. No, that question is asking `nameOf` interface on runtime instead of object to object mapping in type guard. but one of their answers provided a hint to get the name of interface on type guard. tried, it only check props but not the object class itself, if two classes have same props. will return wrong result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @TobiasS. , I found a solution to do value to key mapping in a tricky way.

First by picking value and than exclude it from the interface key. the object should remain one key value pair. `keyof` it will get the name of the value.

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]
type PickByValue<T, V extends T[keyof T]> = { [ K in Exclude<keyof T, ValueOf<{ [ P in keyof T ]: T[P] extends V ? never : P }>> ]: T[K] }
type KeyOfValue<T, V extends T[keyof T]> = keyof PickByValue<T, V>
type PickValueByKey<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never
```

#### Usage:

```
interface Blueberry { strawberry: boolean; }
interface Car { vehicle: number; asdf: never }
interface Apple { vehicle: number; strawberry: boolean; }

interface ModelMap {
  Car: Car
  Apple: Apple
  Blueberry: Blueberry
}

type AppleName = KeyOfValue<ModelMap, Apple>
```

To answer my question:
I can make it simpler like this withput terrible extends chain:

```
interface ModelMap {
  Article: Article
  User: User
}
type ModelName<M extends ValueOf<ModelMap>> = KeyOfValue<ModelMap, M>

interface ModelOptionMap {
  Article: Prisma.ArticleSelect
  User: Prisma.UserSelect
}
type Options<M> = ModelName<M> extends keyof ModelOptionMap ? ModelOptionMap[ModelName<M>] : never
const options: Options<User> = {}
```